# Which one is the subject in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

With courage came determination, and Sucheng was determined to walk again.

My question is Which one is the **subject** in "**with courage came determination**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has got two clauses: a) With courage came determination (reworded: Determination came with courage.), and b) Sucheng was determined to walk again. Thus there are two subjects; one is Determination, and the other Sucheng.